# ProcessBuilder in java not executing the 'java -jar' command

Tags: java, cmd, jar, process, processbuilder

I am trying to execute the windows' commands(which we can execute through command prompt), through java code, using processbuilder, and get response. My program works fine for commands like 'dir', but doesnt work for 'java -jar'. When I give 'java -jar C:\mypath\filename.jar' it is waiting for ever and even not getting any input from the stream. Can you please help on this.
Note: It is working fine if we do that through command prompt.

```
public byte[] execute(String command) {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
        LOG.info("Executing the command {} ...", command);

        builder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", command);

        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        try {
            Process process = builder.start();
            StringBuffer outStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            StreamGobbler streamGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), x -> {
                outStringBuffer.append(x).append("\n");
            });
            Future<?> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(streamGobbler);
            future.get(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//Waiting for 120 seconds and throwing error with null.
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();// If we skip prev step, waiting for ever for this process.
            System.out.println("ExitCode:"+exitCode);

            // assert exitCode == 0;
            if (exitCode == 0) {
                LOG.info("Command \'{}\' executed. And response:{}", command, outStringBuffer.toString());
                return outStringBuffer.toString().getBytes();
            } else {
                LOG.error("Command \'{}\' executed. And process exited with exitCode:{}. Response stored:{}.", command,
                        exitCode, outStringBuffer.toString());
                return ("Process exited with exitCode" + exitCode).getBytes();
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            LOG.error("Error in execution of command:{}. Details of error:{}.{}", command, e.getMessage(), e);
            return ("Error in execution of command:" + command + ". Details of error:" + e.getMessage() + "." + e)
                    .getBytes();
        }
    }


    public class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private Consumer<String> consumer;

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream inputStream, Consumer<String> consumer) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).lines().forEach(consumer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized, it is mistake with handling the Future and process if the subprocess is taking too long to finish. Updated the code to handle.

```
try {
                future.get(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                readerTimedOut = true;
                LOG.info("The Reader for the process did not complete till timeout seconds:{}", 120);
            }
int processTimeOutSeconds = 40;
            if (readerTimedOut) {
                processTimeOutSeconds = 0;
            }
            boolean isProcessTerminated = process.waitFor(processTimeOutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```